# Spark Thrift 3.2.2 impersonate user facing error with metastore authen. SASL negotiation failure, GSS initiate failed

Tags: apache-spark, bigdata, ambari, hive-metastore, spark-thriftserver

On hadoop kerberized cluster. If im not impersonate user on spark thrift server. It work well. But when i do it. Im facing an error about authentication with metastore.

I flow this document

```
https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.4/bk_spark-component-guide/content/config-sts-user-imp.html

https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.4/bk_data-access/content/ref-5422cb60-d1d5-425a-b719-ec7bd03ee5d3.1.html
```

Step 1:

- Set hive.server2.enable.doAs = true **in Advanced spark-hive-site-override**
- Add spark.jars = /usr/hdp/current/spark-thriftserver/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar,/usr/hdp/current/spark-thriftserver/lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar,/usr/hdp/current/spark-thriftserver/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar **in Custom spark-thrift-sparkconf**

Step 2: **in Advanced hiveserver2-site**

- Set hive.security.authorization.enabled = true
- Set hive.server2.enable.doAs = true
- Set hive.metastore.pre.event.listeners = org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.authorization.AuthorizationPreEventListener
- Set hive.security.metastore.authorization.manager = org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.authorization.StorageBasedAuthorizationProvider

Step 3:

- I created a user keytab and princinpal and kinit
- Run cli: beeline -u 'jdbc:hive2://:/default;principal=spark3/@;auth=KERBEROS;transportMode=binary'

> ```
>  Result:
> Connecting to jdbc:hive2://<host>:<port>/default;principal=spark3/<HOST>@<REAM>;auth=KERBEROS;transportMode=binary
> Connected to: Spark SQL (version 3.2.2)
> Driver: Hive JDBC (version 3.1.0.3.1.4.0-315)
> Transaction isolation: TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ
> Beeline version 3.1.0.3.1.4.0-315 by Apache Hive
> ```

- Run cli: show databases;

And I'm facing an error like this

```
Error: org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error running query: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
    ....
Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
    ....
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
....
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
    ....
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
....
Caused by: MetaException(message:Could not connect to meta store using any of the URIs provided. Most recent failure: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: GSS initiate failed
```

I checked log of spark thrift see like that

```
22/10/07 15:07:31 INFO ThriftCLIService: Client protocol version: HIVE_CLI_SERVICE_PROTOCOL_V10
22/10/07 15:07:31 INFO HiveSessionImpl: Operation log session directory is created: /tmp/spark3/operation_logs/64eb19a6-1bdc-4ed8-81c9-8881c4251e75
22/10/07 15:07:31 INFO metastore: Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://<host>:<port>
22/10/07 15:07:32 INFO metastore: Opened a connection to metastore, current connections: 1
22/10/07 15:07:32 INFO metastore: Connected to metastore.
22/10/07 15:07:39 INFO SparkExecuteStatementOperation: Submitting query 'show databases' with fdcf90cb-74bb-4574-99b7-bfd981ce8010
22/10/07 15:07:39 INFO SparkExecuteStatementOperation: Running query with fdcf90cb-74bb-4574-99b7-bfd981ce8010
22/10/07 15:07:39 INFO metastore: Closed a connection to metastore, current connections: 0
22/10/07 15:07:39 INFO metastore: Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://<host>:<port>
22/10/07 15:07:39 ERROR TSaslTransport: SASL negotiation failure
javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
    
Caused by: GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)
    
22/10/07 15:07:39 WARN metastore: Failed to connect to the MetaStore Server...
22/10/07 15:07:39 INFO metastore: Waiting 5 seconds before next connection attempt.
22/10/07 15:07:44 INFO metastore: Trying to connect to metastore with URI  thrift://<host>:<port>
22/10/07 15:07:44 ERROR TSaslTransport: SASL negotiation failure
javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
```

I test connect to spark thrift server successed, but when i run query. Im facing error above. Where am i wrong?

Comment: Who facing this problem like me?

Comment: I tried many different way but, no one of these worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark Thrift Server is built upon a single spark application, unfortunately, it does not support impersonation yet.

Maybe you can try Apache Kyuubi https://github.com/apache/incubator-kyuubi

Comment: Yes, i decided use kybuui and it's perfect

Comment: @qxk71551 since you tried, does kyuubi support impersonation with a kerberized metastore? I'm facing exactly the same issue you had with the STS. BTW it is still not clear to me why in the cloudera documentation you posted they describe impersonation within the STS as something working. Did they implement a customized STS for their CDP?